# deploy cloudera on azure FAILED, error with JSON / ARM template function 'copyIndex'

Tags: json, azure, cloudera

I m trying to install cloudera on azure using the link below https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/cloudera-on-centos It gave me error
"message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'master-node' at line '493' and column '9' is not valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details

The code looks like this

```
        "name": "master-node",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/shared-resources"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "uri": "[concat(variables('scriptsUri'), '/master-node.json')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
                    "parameters": {
    "vnetID": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "resourceAPIVersion": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dnsNamePrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "azuredevcluster"
    },
    "scriptsUri": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccount": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "vmCount": {
      "type": "int"
    },
    "vmSpec": {
      "type": "secureObject"
    },
    "networkSpec": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "clusterSpec": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
                      "variables": {
    "singleQuote": "'",
    "masterIP": "[parameters('networkSpec').masterIP]",
    "workerIP": "[parameters('networkSpec').workerIP]",
    "vmName": "[concat(parameters('dnsNamePrefix'), '-mn')]",
    "nicName": "[concat(variables('vmName'), '-nic')]",
    "publicIPAddressName": "[concat(variables('vmName'), '-publicIP')]",
    "storageAccountName": "[parameters('storageAccount').prefix]",
    "securityGroupName": "[concat(parameters('dnsNamePrefix'), '-mn-sg')]"
  },
                    "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "name": "[variables('securityGroupName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "SSH",
            "properties": {
              "description": "Allows SSH traffic",
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "22",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 100,
              "direction": "Inbound"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "publicIPLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[concat(parameters('dnsNamePrefix'), '-mn', copyIndex())]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(variables('nicName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', variables('securityGroupName'))]"
      ],
      "copy": {
        "name": "masterNodeNicLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
              "privateIPAddress": "[concat(parameters('networkSpec').ipOctet01, add(parameters('networkSpec').ipOctet2, div(copyIndex(parameters('networkSpec').ipOctet3), 256)), '.', mod(copyIndex(parameters('networkSpec').ipOctet3), 256))]",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[concat(parameters('vnetID'), '/subnets/', parameters('networkSpec').virtualNetworkSubnetName)]"
              },
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex()))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "networkSecurityGroup": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('securityGroupName'))]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex())]",
      "plan": "[parameters('vmSpec').imageInfo.plan]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy":{
        "name": "masterNodeNicLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'), copyIndex())]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "availabilitySet": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', parameters('vmSpec').masterNodeASName)]"
        },
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSpec').vmSize]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[reference(concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())).dnsSettings.fqdn]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('vmSpec').adminUsername]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('vmSpec').adminPassword]",
          "linuxConfiguration": {
            "disablePasswordAuthentication": false
          }
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": "[parameters('vmSpec').imageInfo.imageReference]",
          "osDisk": {
            "name":"[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_OSDisk')]",
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          },
          "dataDisks": [
            {
              "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk1')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 512,
              "lun": 0,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            },
            {
              "name":  "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk2')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 512,
              "lun": 1,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            },
            {
              "name":  "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk3')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 512,
              "lun": 2,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            },
            {
              "name":  "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk4')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 512,
              "lun": 3,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',concat(variables('nicName'), copyIndex()))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(), '/prepareDisks')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "nameNodeNicLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'), copyIndex())]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": [
            "[concat(parameters('scriptsUri'), '/scripts/prepare-masternode-disks.sh')]",
            "[concat(parameters('scriptsUri'), '/scripts/initialize-node.sh')]"
          ],
          "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh initialize-node.sh ', variables('singleQuote'), variables('masterIP'), variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), variables('workerIP'), variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), parameters('dnsNamePrefix'), variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), reference(concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())).dnsSettings.fqdn, variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), parameters('clusterSpec').masterNodeCount, variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), parameters('clusterSpec').dataNodeCount, variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), parameters('vmSpec').adminUsername, variables('singleQuote'), ' ', 'masternode', ' >> /var/log/cloudera-azure-initialize.log 2>&1')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "fqdn": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), '0')).dnsSettings.fqdn]"
    }
  }
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "vnetID": {
                        "value": "[variables('VNetId')]"
                    },
                    "resourceAPIVersion": {
                        "value": "[variables('resourceAPIVersion')]"
                    },
                    "dnsNamePrefix": {
                        "value": "[parameters('dnsNamePrefix')]"
                    },
                    "scriptsUri": {
                        "value": "[variables('scriptsUri')]"
                    },
                    "storageAccount": {
                        "value": "[variables('masterStorageAccount')]"
                    },
                    "vmCount": {
                        "value": "[variables('clusterSpec').masterNodeCount]"
                    },
                    "vmSpec": {
                        "value": "[variables('vmSpec')]"
                    },
                    "networkSpec": {
                        "value": "[variables('networkSpec')]"
                    },
                    "clusterSpec": {
                        "value": "[variables('clusterSpec')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "data-node",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/shared-resources"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "uri": "[variables('data-nodeUri')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
                    "parameters": {
    "vnetID": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "dnsNamePrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "azuredevcluster"
    },
    "scriptsUri": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vmCount": {
      "type": "int"
    },
    "vmSpec": {
      "type": "secureObject"
    },
    "networkSpec": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "clusterSpec": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
                     "variables": {
    "singleQuote": "'",
    "masterIP": "[parameters('networkSpec').masterIP]",
    "workerIP": "[parameters('networkSpec').workerIP]",
    "vmName": "[concat(parameters('dnsNamePrefix'), '-dn')]",
    "nicName": "[concat(variables('vmName'), '-nic')]",
    "publicIPAddressName": "[concat(variables('vmName'), '-publicIP')]",
    "securityGroupName": "[concat(parameters('dnsNamePrefix'), '-dn-sg')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
      "name": "[variables('securityGroupName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "securityRules": [
          {
            "name": "SSH",
            "properties": {
              "description": "Allows SSH traffic",
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "sourcePortRange": "*",
              "destinationPortRange": "22",
              "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
              "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
              "access": "Allow",
              "priority": 100,
              "direction": "Inbound"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "publicIPLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[concat(parameters('dnsNamePrefix'), '-dn', copyIndex())]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(variables('nicName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/', variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', variables('securityGroupName'))]"
      ],
      "copy": {
        "name": "dataNodeNicLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
              "privateIPAddress": "[concat(parameters('networkSpec').ipOctet01, add(parameters('networkSpec').ipOctet2, div(copyIndex(parameters('networkSpec').datanodeIpOctet3), 256)), '.', mod(copyIndex(parameters('networkSpec').datanodeIpOctet3), 256))]",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[concat(parameters('vnetID'), '/subnets/', parameters('networkSpec').virtualNetworkSubnetName)]"
              },
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex()))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "networkSecurityGroup": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('securityGroupName'))]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-30",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex())]",
      "plan": {
        "name": "cloudera-centos-6",
        "publisher": "cloudera",
        "product": "cloudera-centos-6"
      },
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "dataNodeNicLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', variables('nicName'), copyIndex())]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "availabilitySet": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets', parameters('vmSpec').dataNodeASName)]"
        },
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSpec').vmSize]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[reference(concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())).dnsSettings.fqdn]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('vmSpec').adminUsername]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('vmSpec').adminPassword]",
          "linuxConfiguration": {
            "disablePasswordAuthentication": false
          }
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "cloudera",
            "offer": "cloudera-centos-6",
            "sku": "cloudera-centos-6",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_OSDisk')]",
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          },
          "dataDisks": [
            {
              "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk1')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 512,
              "lun": 0,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            },
            {
              "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk2')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 1023,
              "lun": 1,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            },
            {
              "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk3')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 1023,
              "lun": 2,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            },
            {
              "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk4')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 1023,
              "lun": 3,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            },
            {
              "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk5')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 1023,
              "lun": 4,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            },
            {
              "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(),'_DataDisk6')]",
              "diskSizeGB": 1023,
              "lun": 5,
              "createOption": "Empty"
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',concat(variables('nicName'), copyIndex()))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'), copyIndex(), '/prepareDisks')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "dataNodeNicLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'), copyIndex())]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions",
        "type": "CustomScript",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.0",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": [
            "[concat(parameters('scriptsUri'), '/scripts/prepare-datanode-disks.sh')]",
            "[concat(parameters('scriptsUri'), '/scripts/initialize-node.sh')]"
          ],
          "commandToExecute": "[concat('sh initialize-node.sh ', variables('singleQuote'), variables('masterIP'), variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), variables('workerIP'), variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), parameters('dnsNamePrefix'), variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), reference(concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())).dnsSettings.fqdn, variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), parameters('clusterSpec').masterNodeCount, variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), parameters('clusterSpec').dataNodeCount, variables('singleQuote'), ' ', variables('singleQuote'), parameters('vmSpec').adminUsername, variables('singleQuote'), ' ', 'datanode', ' >> /var/log/cloudera-azure-initialize.log 2>&1')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "vnetID": {
                        "value": "[variables('VNetId')]"
                    },
                    "templateAPIVersion": {
                        "value": "[variables('templateAPIVersion')]"
                    },
                    "resourceAPIVersion": {
                        "value": "[variables('resourceAPIVersion')]"
                    },
                    "dnsNamePrefix": {
                        "value": "[parameters('dnsNamePrefix')]"
                    },
                    "scriptsUri": {
                        "value": "[variables('scriptsUri')]"
                    },
                    "storageAccount": {
                        "value": "[variables('workerStorageAccount')]"
                    },
                    "vmCount": {
                        "value": "[variables('clusterSpec').dataNodeCount]"
                    },
                    "vmSpec": {
                        "value": "[variables('vmSpec')]"
                    },
                    "networkSpec": {
                        "value": "[variables('networkSpec')]"
                    },
                    "clusterSpec": {
                        "value": "[variables('clusterSpec')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "setup-cloudera",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
            "dependsOn": [
                "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/data-node",
                "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/master-node"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "uri": "[concat(variables('scriptsUri'), '/setup-cloudera.json')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "resourceAPIVersion": {
                        "value": "[variables('resourceAPIVersion')]"
                    },
                    "dnsNamePrefix": {
                        "value": "[parameters('dnsNamePrefix')]"
                    },
                    "scriptsUri": {
                        "value": "[variables('scriptsUri')]"
                    },
                    "vmSpec": {
                        "value": "[variables('vmSpec')]"
                    },
                    "networkSpec": {
                        "value": "[variables('networkSpec')]"
                    },
                    "clusterSpec": {
                        "value": "[variables('clusterSpec')]"
                    },
                    "fqdn": {
                        "value": "[reference('master-node').outputs.fqdn.value]"
                    },
                    "cmUsername": {
                        "value": "[parameters('cmUsername')]"
                    },
                    "cmPassword": {
                        "value": "[parameters('cmPassword')]"
                    },
                    "company": {
                        "value": "[parameters('Company')]"
                    },
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "value": "[parameters('emailAddress')]"
                    },
                    "businessPhone": {
                        "value": "[parameters('businessPhone')]"
                    },
                    "firstName": {
                        "value": "[parameters('firstName')]"
                    },
                    "lastName": {
                        "value": "[parameters('lastName')]"
                    },
                    "jobRole": {
                        "value": "[parameters('jobRole')]"
                    },
                    "jobFunction": {
                        "value": "[parameters('jobFunction')]"
                    },
                    "installCDH": {
                        "value": "[variables('installCDH')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: which link\template are you using to deploy? its pretty weird its a solution that doesnt work

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  I do appreciate it.   There was not enough space here to include the whole code, so I included just part of the code from where the error initiates.   I deploy  https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/cloudera-on-centos/azuredeploy.json    ; this calls master-node deployment  https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/cloudera-on-centos/master-node.json;  where from the copyindex error comes from

Comment: theres just too much stuff going on here, i suggest you contact the owners and let them know their stuff is broken

Comment: Do you mean there are lots of issues with the code ?   Could you give an example ?   I faced with a few errors and solved those .  The last error that I have faced with is this one.  Where can I send you my JSON file ?

Comment: pastebin or something like that? example: they had no api version attached to the resource. that could never work

Comment: take a look at this  https://gist.github.com/stefankam/4c75931884dad8a2da95ef16f4f95d9a

Answer (score 0):

yeah so, I've found the problem (but there will probably be more problems after that, sadly). problem comes from the fact you are using nested INLINE templates and how they work (or rather not) with the reference function:

```
"[reference(concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())).dnsSettings.fqdn]",
```

this is the part thats breaking. so my advice would be to either make this a single template, without nesting those, or convert those to a full blown nested templates (using `templateLink` property, not `template` property:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
            "uri": "url_goes_here"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "prefix": {
                "value": "xxx"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I would suggest that you never use nested INLINE templates. they are just too edgy.

Comment: thanks a lot :)  do you accept a job to fix this code ?

Comment: sure ;) you can find link to my blog on my profile, and there is an about page with contacts

Comment: with lots of thanks, the answer above did not help for the error BELOW    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928022/deploy-cloudera-on-azure-failed-error-with-arm-template-function-copyindex