# Deploy Cloudera cluster on azure FAILED , JSON/ARM template issue

Tags: json, azure-devops

I m trying to install cloudera on azure using the link below https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/cloudera-on-centos It gave me a few errors, below deploy cloudera on centos Required property 'resources' not found in JSON

I solved it. BUT I m now stuck at some point. "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template 'copy' definition at line '0' and column '0' is missing a copy input value.

I use copy for resources, not for properties, there is no need for input value.

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[concat(variables('publicIPAddressName'), copyIndex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": [{
        "name": "publicIPLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
      }],
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[concat(parameters('dnsNamePrefix'), '-dn', copyIndex())]"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy should look like this:

```
  "copy": {
    "name": "publicIPLoop",
    "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
  },
```

its an object, not an array

Comment: Initially there was no bracket , it gave me another error: "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'master-node' at line '493' and column '9' is not valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified. 
I googled and saw the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270901/copyindex-error-in-arm-template
I put the brackets, which does not make sense, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple

Comment: the `[]` syntax is needed for properties copy, not for regular copy. this should work right now, at least the part you are showing in your question is valid if you implement this fix

Comment: THANKS for your prompt response. Again I receive the error that I used to receive without bracket.   "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'master-node' at line '493' and column '9' is not valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.

Comment: well, thats another resource. i suggest you accept this answer and start a new question with this error

Comment: ok, as you say.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800940/deploy-cloudera-on-azure-failed-error-with-json-arm-template-function-copyin/53854513#53854513

Answer (score 0):

THANKS A LOT  for your response, 
Initially there was no bracket , it gave me another error:
 "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'master-node' at line '493' and column '9' is not valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'."

I googled it,  and I saw the post
[copyindex() error in arm template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270901/copyindex-error-in-arm-template)

I put the brackets, to make it an array,  and now it asks me for input,  which does not make sense, according to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple